# What is the correct way to store a X.509 private key in an environment variable on Vercel and use it in Nextjs?

Tags: next.js, vercel

### The Setup

I have a Nextjs app that uses Firebase Admin and requires a private key to initialize itself. It is a X.509 private key cert and to be safe I'm trying to store it in environment variables on Vercel - my hosting choice.

I have environment variables in a `.env.local` file as described in the nextjs [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables).
Since [several](https://github.com/vercel/vercel/issues/749#issuecomment-707515089) [places](https://dev.to/cfofiu/how-to-store-a-long-private-key-in-vercel-s-environment-variables-46f5) describe private keys stored "raw" not being stored properly by Vercel, but that they can be stored properly as JSON and later parsed by the app, I have done this.
Indeed testing storing the private key as is didn't work, and storing/parsing it in either of the two methods described on this [github issue](https://github.com/vercel/vercel/issues/749#issuecomment-707515089) works locally with my variables in `.env.local` like so:

```
EXAMPLE_KEY=example_value
FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY='"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\WdEFiwPk...   ...htJthGef\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"'
```

### The Problem

Trying to deploy these changes to Vercel has failed, and looking into why seems to point to environment variables stored in a wierd way on Vercel.

Using the Vercel cli to add a variable, and then supplying the text will always wrap the value supplied with double quotes:

If you `vercel env add FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY` and input `true` for the value,
And then run `vercel env pull <filename>`, the file will contain:

```
FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY="true"
```

This might not be a problem normally, but since the private key has double quotes wrapping it, submitting the value "raw" and then pulling it back to a local file looks like:

```
FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY=""-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\WdEFiwPk...   ...htJthGef\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n""
```

And trying to submit it in the JSON parse-able single quoted string returns:

```
FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY="'"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\WdEFiwPk...   ...htJthGef\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"'"
```

I thought that might just be how the data is formatted when pulled from Vercel, but it lines up with the error messages I was seeing from the app.

I've tried just about every combination and configuration to try and get a `JSON.parse`-able private key but can't seem to get it working. I even tried removing the double quotes wrapping the `privateKey`, seeing if the apparent added double quotes would be added and work there, but no dice.

Answer (score 6):

Credit to: https://gist.github.com/tomi/0675e58919af4554b198cee3f84405e5

#### Encoding the private key as base64:

- Copy the private key to clipboard
- Run command `pbpaste | base64 | pbcopy`

The private key is now base64 encoded in the clipboard.
Paste it to env variable e.g. to heroku or to .env file

#### Decoding the private key from base64 in node.js

const private_key = new Buffer(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY, 'base64').toString('ascii');

Comment: With the last version syntax: 
`Buffer.from(process.env.SSH_KEY, 'base64').toString('utf8')`

Answer (score 0):

Believe you can remove the --private-key--- section from the beginning and end, and just use the value in between.

Answer (score 0):

Change

private_key : process.env.GCLOUD_PRIVATE_KEY

by

private_key : process.env.GCLOUD_PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\n/g, '\n')

[source](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node/issues/1173#issuecomment-199183259)